# How to easily assign an undefined number of variables in Python loops

Tags: python, string, loops, tkinter

while coding a GUI with Tkinter I've encountered a problem.

I'm generating a series of buttons and label based on a dynamic list, following there's an example explaining my problem:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x500')
main_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='grey').grid(row=0,column=0)
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for x in range(len(my_list)):
    tk.Button(text='CHECK', command=lambda:print('The value is {}'.format(my_list[x]))).grid(row=x,column=0)
    tk.Label(text=my_list[x]).grid(row=x,column=1)
```

The problem is evident, what i want to do is to print the value corresponding at my_list[x] at the moment of its assignment, but while looping the value of x is reassigned and all the buttons print me the last string in my_list.

Is there a way to store a string value in a case like this? Or every time i should create *n* variables to store the string? Note that my_list length can vary.

Comment: No, don't dynamically create variables. Use a *container* like a list or a dict

Comment: How can i do it if the length of the list can change? (So the variables to create)

Comment: But actually, your issue is different.

Comment: Again **don't dynamically create variables**